# Using multiple JQuery versions and noConflict

Tags: jquery

I'm working with a plugin for an application which has a codebase I do not want to change due to update issues.

The Application is including Jquery 1.3.2 in the header and uses it heavily throughout the site. 
Not thinking about this, I went ahead and wrote my plugin using version 1.8.0
and it turns out this messes up the functions of the original application.

I've been trying to implement the noConflict method but with no success.

```
# Site loads jQuery1.32 and other jQuery plugins

# My awesome php & html code

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);  
$jq.DoSomeJQueryStuff();
</script>
```

How can I implement noConflict in this scenario?

Comment: Are you asking how to call your v1.8 plugin from v1.3 code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it somthing like this you need.

If we suppose the links are added in this order :

1. jquery-1.3.2.js
2. jquery-1.8.0.js

We have this :

```
jQuery.noConflict();

// here you can execute javascript with jquery version 1.3.2
console.log($.fn.jquery);


jQuery(function($){
    // here you can execute javascript with jquery version 1.8.0
    console.log($.fn.jquery);
});
```

You can find an example on this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/w2m5j/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to call `noConflict()` on whichever comes first (or both). Without calling it on the first instance, there will already a "conflict" by the time you include the script definition below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var $jQ180 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
   document.write($jQ180().jquery); // 1.8.0
</script>​

...

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write($().jquery); // 1.3.2
</script>
```

Comment: The problems is that I do not want to change any of the code using 1.3.2

Comment: Is it possible for you to define 1.8 first? For example, if you can place 1.8 in the head above the 1.3.2 definition and call noConflict() on it, I think you'll be OK.

Comment: This work but it forces me to change the code of the main applications header which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: It's essential that 1.3.2 is loaded last and that anything before it has .noConflict() called on it. Otherwise, the original plugins may not work.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.

Comment: changing a header script order is hardly "changing code". If there are no side affects to the old code then it's ok

Comment: @LiviuT. It not much code, but it still will be replaced when the application is updated.